# Sent data to router on click event

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-s3, iron-router

I am using Iron Router to create ZIP Files from Data stored in my AWS S3 Bucket. For that I would like to query my files and only put files into my ZIP Folder based on the data context in my current template.

My current Data context has two fields (_id, filetype) which are used to query my FS.Collection. Unfortunatly only the _id can be used to query my files in the router. I am not able to get filetype to iron router:

My click event:

```
  'click #download': function() {
      Router.go('zip.download', {_id: this._id, _Filetype: this.filetype});
   }
```

My route:

```
/*ZIP Files*/
Router.route('/zip/:_id', {
  where: 'server',
  name: 'zip.download',
  action: function() {
    console.log(this.params); //Gives me only _id, but not _Filetype

    // Create zip
    var zip = new JSZip();
    MyCollection.find({refrenceID: this.params._id, filetype: this.params._Filetype})
    .
    .
    .
    // End Create Zip - This part works 
  }
});
```

Whats the best way to pass data to the router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, your `_Filetype` is not received because it is not declared as a valid parameter in your route: `/zip/:_id`. (no mention of `:_Filetype` in there)

If you don't want to put the fileType as a parameter in your route, you will still have to provide it somehow. This seems a good occasion to use [query parameters](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router#query-parameters)!

In your click event:

```
'click #download': function() {
    Router.go('zip.download', {_id: this._id}, , {query: 'fileType=' +  this.filetype});
}
```

And in your route:

```
/*ZIP Files*/
Router.route('/zip/:_id', {
  where: 'server',
  name: 'zip.download',
  action: function() {
    console.log(this.params); //Gives me only _id, but not _Filetype

    // Create zip
    var zip = new JSZip();
    MyCollection.find({refrenceID: this.params._id, filetype: this.params.query.fileType})
    .
    .
    .
    // End Create Zip - This part works 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. An object instead of the string worked too btw. `{query:{_id: this._id, filetype: this.filetype}}`

Comment: Oh! Good. Yeah, seems cleaner using and object.